# proof by induction - creating summations?

Tags: proof-writing

I have two proofs I need to do that I can not figure out how to turn into summations in order to solve.

1. $3|(4^n-1)$ I believe that $|$ is meant to symbolize $3$ divides ...
2. $n!\le n^n$

I have to write it like this $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=n$$

Comment: #1 is related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697892/proof-that-23n-1-is-divisible-by-11-for-all-positive-integers-n

Comment: i see the connection but I still don't see how to write it out as a $\sum_{k=1}^{n}i=n$ style summation

Comment: why such summation is required?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$#2$

If $\displaystyle n^n\ge n!,$

$\displaystyle  (n+1)^{n+1}=(n+1)\cdot (n+1)^n>(n+1)n^n\ge (n+1)\cdot n!$

Answer (score 0):

1. $4^n = (3+1)^n$.
   When you develop the product, there are only multiple of 3 and the $+1$ obtained multiplying 1 by itself $n$ times. So $4^n - 1$ is a multiple of 3.
2. $n! = n(n-1)\cdots 2\times 1$, and there are $n$ factors. They are all $\le n$, so $$
   n! \le n^n
   $$

Comment: do you know how i could write that as a summation?